# Create or copy table dynamically, using Django db API

Tags: django, django-models

how can I perform smth like
`CREATE TABLE table_b AS SELECT * FROM table_a`
using Django db API?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Django's ORM isn't intended for things like this. I would suggest you're doing something the wrong way but you haven't explained why you want to do this, so I can't really comment.

Anyway. You can use Django's raw SQL:

```
def my_custom_sql():
    from django.db import connection, transaction
    cursor = connection.cursor()

    # Data modifying operation - commit required
    cursor.execute("UPDATE bar SET foo = 1 WHERE baz = %s", [self.baz])
    transaction.commit_unless_managed()

    # Data retrieval operation - no commit required
    cursor.execute("SELECT foo FROM bar WHERE baz = %s", [self.baz])
    row = cursor.fetchone()

    return row
```

http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/sql/#executing-custom-sql-directly

Comment: Thanks. May be I'm really doing something the wrong way.
Well, some values in table are evaluated according to the user's actions. And it's necessary to create check points periodically (max 2-3 check points). I intended to do it by copying table

Answer (score 3):

As an alternative you could potentially leverage South since it has an API for creating and dropping tables.

http://south.aeracode.org/wiki/db.create_table

I haven't tried this outside the context of a migration so no guarantees it will work out-of-the-box.

Answer (score 1):

You can't. You'll have to drop to [DB-API](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0249/).

Comment: You don't. You can let Django manage your DB connection still.

Comment: @Oli: Of course it manages the *connection*, but you still have to use DB-API directly, just like your answer shows.